# How to make sure that csrf validation is being performed? Is there a way to check it?

Tags: python, csrf-protection, django-csrf, django-2.0

I read about how django provides csrf verification for POST data. Following that I added csrf middleware in settings.py and csrf_token in all the html forms. Do I need anything (like a decorator) along with this? and how do i verify that csrf verification is being done.

I added csrf middleware in settings.py and csrf_token in all the html forms and if I remove it, it gives csrf error and sometimes leaving the same page open for a while gives the same request error.

```
<form role="form" class="login-form" action="." method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <span style='color: RED; font-weight: bold;'>{{ error }}</span>
    <div class="form-group">
    <div class="input-icon">
```

Error message given would be "CSRF verification failed or Request Error"

Comment: No, you don't need anything else - from what you've said, the token is doing its job.

Comment: Thanks for your response. so view will verify it when it renders the page? and is there a way to see it/verify it?

Comment: If you view the page source you should see that it renders a hidden input with name `csrfmiddlewaretoken` and value a long "random" string